# Google Sheets - repeat TRANSPOSE WITH QUERY

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

as the graph
I hope I could get the result like red line, just use formula in one row
I try everything I could think of, but it all doesn't work

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7M2S.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 UNIQUE({A2:B, B2:B}), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), " "))
```

[image]